# A detail from the Fermat-prime-test

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

This question comes from a review of an older study of properties of the "fermat-primetest", but where I did not get aware of the following detail.
With a small spreadsheet-like program I can show the following type of spreadsheet:
[image]
We see as index of the columns the number $N$ to be tested, and as index of the rows the base $b$ which should provide the residue $b^{N-1} \pmod N$.
The test with base $b=2$ is much successful: if $N$ is prime, then the residue is $1$.
Just to show the well known problem: there are the Fermat-pseudoprimes, where the residue to base $2$ is as well $1$, but is not prime, see $N=341$. It is also well known that we can repeat the test using base $b=3$ and find that $N$ is composite, because the residue is not $1$.

This is all common knowledge, and I repeat this here only to introduce another question where I do not even have an idea, how to approach this.
We see in prime $N$, that the whole column is $1$ (except the cells where $b \equiv 0 \pmod N$), but moreover we see columns, where the residues have further obvious patterns like $b^{N-1} \equiv b^e \pmod N $ with $e=1$ ($N=346$),$e=2$ ($N=339$),$e=3$ ($N=340$) and so on.

I've tried now to understand the properties of numbers $N$, which have a sequence of residues according to $e=1$ or more explicite $b^{N-1} \equiv b^1 \pmod N$ (the primes $N$ may be interpreted as having residues with $e=0$ or $b^{N-1} \equiv b^0 \pmod N$). Basic pattern-detection with $N$ upto $1024$ didn't reveal something suggestive so far. Perhaps worth to notice: for $N=3^m$ we have $e=3^{m-1}-1$ and for $N=5^m$ we have $e=5^{m-1}-1$ and similar patterns.

So my question is:

> **Is there some knowledge about the structure of $N$ where the residues follow $b^1 \pmod N$?**

*P.S. I had made that observation some years ago, and had put a sequence of the $e$ depending on $N$ in the [OEIS-database](https://oeis.org/A079327) but had then no clue at all how to analyze this*

*P.S.2 According to the hints in comments below, I've seen in OEIS that the occuring sequences (having $e=2$, $e=3$ and so on) are sometimes found with keyword "Knödel-numbers". But this is not always correct; while my sequences give $b^{N-1} \equiv b^e \pmod N$ **where all $b \lt N $ must satisfy the equivalence**, the according sequences of Knödel-numbers test only that $b$ where $\gcd(b,N)=1$, so my sequences are in principle subsequences of the Knödel-sequences, and, in reverse, elements of a Knödel-sequence of order $k$ may occur in my sequences with exponent $e$ with $e \ne k-1$.

For instance, with $e=3$ mysequence begins with $4,    8, 12,     20, 24, 28,$ while the $4$-Knödel-sequence begins with $    6, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28,$. The $6$ in the $4$-Knödel-sequence occurs with $e=1$ in my sequences, and the $16$ in $4$-Knödel occurs with $e=7$ in my sequences. A singular sequence in OEIS, where this matches perfectly as well in the description, is for instance [OEIS A216090](https://oeis.org/A216090)*

Comment: They are squarefree 2-Knodel numbers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kn%C3%B6del_number)

Comment: and for $b^2$ they are the 3-Knodel numbers (not squarefree this time I think)

Comment: more generally there is a link between $b^e$ and the ($e+1$)-Knodel numbers, but it is not always straightforward (for even?). I looked at this a long time ago, but I am currently going to sleep. I will dig my notes tommorow if I find some time

Comment: If you test $b^{N} \equiv b^{e+1} \pmod N$ instead of $b^{N-1} \equiv b^e \pmod N$ (multiply by $b$ on both sides), you will get the ($e+1$)-Knödel numbers without the gcd condition (except for 2-Knödel numbers where you have to skip multiple of 8 ?!? and the 1-Knödel numbers which should include prime numbers)

Comment: I tried with $b^{N-1} \equiv b^e \pmod N$ and there is a mismatch on a few numbers when $e=3$ (or 0, or 1) ,but it seems to be ok for $e>3$. Pari/Gp code to test if n is k-Knodel:  is_k_Knodel(n,k)=(n>k)&&0==((n-k)%lcm(znstar(n)[2]))

Comment: @user489810 - thanks for the Pari/GP formula. I've never worked with znstar(), only with znorder(). I'll look at it. Meanwhile, unfortunately I must regress: my tables have been incomplete for higher $e$, because my routine searched only for the first (smallest) $e$ and did not take in account, that some $N$ in the sequence for, say, $e=4$ might as well occur in $e+k \cdot \Delta$ up to $N-1$ and so my working lists (and some conclusions from patterns and some little algebra) is not correct. Currently I'm trying to fix this/to extend my working lists.

Comment: Something to do with cyclic groups and you can also use znstar(n)[2][1] instead of lcm(znstar(n)[2]). It is the Carmichael function of n, and you basically check if the Carmichael function of n divides n-k (with n>k).

Answer (score 1):

Well, $346$ seems to be a member of a family of numbers of form $2p$. If $N=2p$, where $p$ is an odd prime, then $a^{n-1} = a^{2p-1} \equiv a \pmod{p}$ and obviously $a^{n-1} \equiv a \pmod{2}$, so $a^{n-1} \equiv a \pmod N$. By the same calculation, $N=2C$ where $C$ is a Carmichael number also works.

In the general case, any such $N$ should be square-free (otherwise if $p^2 \mid N$ taking $a$ divisible by $p$ would always give $a^{n-1}$ divisible by $p^2$). Moreover, in an analogous way to the property of Carmichael numbers, for any prime divisor $p$ of $N$ we should have $p-1 \mid N-2$ (this is just writing down Fermat's little theorem). But that means if $N$ has any odd prime divisor, then $p-1$ is even, so $N$ has to be even too. So we can write $N=2M$, with $M$ being odd square-free number.

Now our first guess would probably be that $M$ is either a prime or a Carmichael number, but this is probably not true – the condition for $M$ is somewhat weaker. I would assume that we can find some additional examples, but it seems you have a lot of data on the topic, so you can search for such examples yourself. Probably they will appear much less often than primes, but I'd guess a bit more often than Carmichael numbers.

Comment: Hmm, I can provide a short list of $N<=1000$ with $e=1$. Didn't see much pattern except that $N \equiv 2 \pmod 4$ : {2    6   10   14   22   26
   30   34   38   46   58   62
   74   82   86   94  106  118
  122  134  142  146  158  166
  178  182  194  202  206  214
  218  226  254  262  274  278
  298  302  314  326  334  346
  358  362  382  386  394  398
  422  446  454  458  466  478
  482  502  514  526  538  542
  554  562  566  586  614  622
  626  634  662  674  694  698
  706  718  734  746  758  766
  778  794  802  818  838  842
  862  866  870  878  886  898}

Comment: Yes, so most of them are of form $2p$ where $p$ is a prime, and we have four exceptions: 2 (this one's not too interesting), 30=2*3*5, 182=2*7*13 and 870=2*3*5*29.

Comment: Hmmm. Just a quick re-run: this are the exceptions with $N<10000$: $$\small \begin{bmatrix} 
 2 & 2 \\ 
 30 & 2.3.5 \\ 
 182 & 2.7.13 \\ 
 870 & 2.3.5.29 \\ 
 1122 & 2.3.11.17 \\ 
 1406 & 2.19.37 \\ 
 2210 & 2.5.13.17 \\ 
 3458 & 2.7.13.19 \\ 
 3782 & 2.31.61 \\ 
 4930 & 2.5.17.29 \\ 
 5402 & 2.37.73 \\ 
 5642 & 2.7.13.31 \\ 
 6734 & 2.7.13.37
 \end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: Five of them (1122, 2210, 3458, 4930 and 5643) come from Carmichael numbers. 6734 looks interesting, as it has four prime divisors and is not a double of Carmichael number, the only such number on the list (although probably there are many more).

Comment: Hmm, looks somehow irregular. Up to $N<30000$: $$ \small \begin{bmatrix} 
 11102 & 2.7.13.61 \\ 
 13202 & 2.7.23.41 \\ 
 17390 & 2.5.37.47 \\ 
 17822 & 2.7.19.67 \\ 
 21170 & 2.5.29.73 \\ 
 22610 & 2.5.7.17.19 \\ 
 24806 & 2.79.157 \\ 
 27962 & 2.11.31.41 
 \end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: All examples of form $2pq$ are for $q=2p-1$, so something similar to Sophie Germain primes (but with a minus instead of a plus) (this follows from writing down appropriate divisibilities).

Comment: Nice observation! I'll see whether I can proceed in that spirit...

Comment: If I look at numbers $N$ with $e=2$ then $N$ displayed in numbersystem base $3$ the digit sums are all odd; with $e=4$ and base $5$ the digit sums seem to be $\in \{1,5,9,13,...\}$. Unfortunately they give not the full sets of solutions...

Answer (score 0):

I still cannot discern any meaningful pattern for this, but the following (a bit more comprehensive) list might allow some enlightening idea ...

---

We look at the cases with a given exponent $e$ where for some $N$ the following equivalency holds:
$$    b^{N-1} \equiv b^e \pmod{N} \qquad \text{for } 1 \le b \le N-1 \tag 1
$$
For $e=0$ this gives the list with all $N$ being prime. (The Carmichael-numbers are *not* part of this list, there are bases $b<N$ for which $b^{N-1} \not \equiv b^0 \pmod N$ for instance $N=561$ needs $e=80$ to fit the bill).

For $e>1$ we find mostly $N$ where $N/(e+1)$ is prime -let's call them the "regular cases" -, but additionally cases $N$, where $N/(e+1)$ are composite. Let's call those additional cases the set of "irregular $N$ for exponent $e$" .

In the following I document the first $15$ irregular $N$ divided by $e+1$ for exponents $e=1..9$.
Here the sequence of $N/(e+1)$ for $e=1$ is [known to the OEIS](https://oeis.org/A180248), but not (yet) that for the higher $e$. I also have no clue for their significance so far.

**Table1:** Values show $N/(e+1)$  for irregular $N$ :
$$\small \begin{array} {r|rr}
\text{e} & \\ \hline
 1 & 1 & 15 & 91 & 435 & 561 & 703 & 1105 & 1729 & 1891 & 2465 & 2701 & 2821 & 3367 & 5551 & 6601 \\ 
 2 & 1 & 21 & 65 & 105 & 133 & 231 & 273 & 341 & 481 & 561 & 645 & 651 & 1001 & 1105 & 1281 \\ 
 3 & 1 & 6 & 10 & 15 & 30 & 66 & 70 & 85 & 91 & 130 & 190 & 286 & 370 & 435 & 451 \\ 
 4 & 1 & 33 & 165 & 217 & 385 & 561 & 793 & 1045 & 1065 & 1105 & 1353 & 1705 & 1729 & 2465 & 2665 \\ 
 5 & 1 & 4 & 6 & 12 & 14 & 15 & 21 & 28 & 35 & 39 & 42 & 65 & 66 & 76 & 84 \\ 
 6 & 1 & 145 & 301 & 781 & 1105 & 1729 & 1885 & 1921 & 2413 & 2821 & 3913 & 5365 & 5713 & 6541 & 6601 \\ 
 7 & 1 & 4 & 6 & 10 & 12 & 15 & 20 & 28 & 30 & 51 & 52 & 60 & 66 & 70 & 85 \\ 
 8 & 1 & 21 & 57 & 65 & 105 & 133 & 185 & 231 & 273 & 285 & 341 & 399 & 481 & 561 & 645 \\ 
 9 & 1 & 15 & 33 & 55 & 91 & 165 & 205 & 217 & 385 & 403 & 427 & 435 & 561 & 697 & 703
 \end{array}
$$
**Table2:** Values show (irregular) $N$ :
$$ \small \begin{array} {r|rr} e & \\ \hline  
 1 & 2 & 30 & 182 & 870 & 1122 & 1406 & 2210 & 3458 & 3782 & 4930 & 5402 & 5642 & 6734 & 11102 & 13202 \\ 
 2 & 3 & 63 & 195 & 315 & 399 & 693 & 819 & 1023 & 1443 & 1683 & 1935 & 1953 & 3003 & 3315 & 3843 \\ 
 3 & 4 & 24 & 40 & 60 & 120 & 264 & 280 & 340 & 364 & 520 & 760 & 1144 & 1480 & 1740 & 1804 \\ 
 4 & 5 & 165 & 825 & 1085 & 1925 & 2805 & 3965 & 5225 & 5325 & 5525 & 6765 & 8525 & 8645 & 12325 & 13325 \\ 
 5 & 6 & 24 & 36 & 72 & 84 & 90 & 126 & 168 & 210 & 234 & 252 & 390 & 396 & 456 & 504 \\ 
 6 & 7 & 1015 & 2107 & 5467 & 7735 & 12103 & 13195 & 13447 & 16891 & 19747 & 27391 & 37555 & 39991 & 45787 & 46207 \\ 
 7 & 8 & 32 & 48 & 80 & 96 & 120 & 160 & 224 & 240 & 408 & 416 & 480 & 528 & 560 & 680 \\ 
 8 & 9 & 189 & 513 & 585 & 945 & 1197 & 1665 & 2079 & 2457 & 2565 & 3069 & 3591 & 4329 & 5049 & 5805 \\ 
 9 & 10 & 150 & 330 & 550 & 910 & 1650 & 2050 & 2170 & 3850 & 4030 & 4270 & 4350 & 5610 & 6970 & 7030
 \end{array}
$$